# Best possible ways to copy link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm looking for a suitable way to copy URL (link) to the clipboard.

Can someone tell me how this can be achieved?

```js
function copyURL() {      
  var elem = document.createElement("textarea");      
  document.body.appendChild(elem);      
  elem.value = google.com;      
  elem.select();      
  document.execCommand("copy");      
  document.body.removeChild(elem);      
  document.write("Copied to clipboard!");
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:void(1);" onclick="copyURL()">Copy URL</a>
```

Comment: A more detailed question with your requirements would allow others to help you a little more - for example, include your comments (that you wrote on answers below) about it needing to be 'on click', needing a success message, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`document.execCommand("copy");`

Fiddle:  [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z8dshg4u/)

Comment: any example please?

Comment: Can I not do it on a hyperlink? Like I click on the hyperlink and it copies the value at the back with a message. Copied to cllipboard?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.location.href` and `.execCommand` on a hidden `textarea`:

```js
var url = document.getElementById('url')
url.value = location.href
url.select()
document.execCommand("copy");
```

```html
Not hidden for example:<br>
<textarea id="url"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try making a dummy input, copying it, then removing it.

```js
function copyURL() {      
  var elem = document.createElement("textarea");      
  document.body.appendChild(elem);      
  elem.value = location.href;      
  elem.select();      
  document.execCommand("copy");      
  document.body.removeChild(elem);      
  document.write("Copied to clipboard!");
}
```

```html
<button onclick="copyURL()">Copy URL</button>
```

Comment: Why does it open a paste box? Can it just not say, copied to the clipboard?

Comment: @BillNathan It's so you can make sure it worked by pasting it into the prompt.

Comment: Can you remove it? I can try and paste somewhere else? Just show a message saying. Copied to clipboard, please?

Comment: No problem @BillNathan.

Comment: Edited @BillNathan, any better?

Comment: Two things. Can this button be an anchor link? And what if I want to set the link of my choice instead of current URL?

Comment: Just change the `location.href` to whatever link you want.

Comment: What about changing it from button to anchor link?

Comment: Just change the tag type - from `<button>` to `<a href="#">`.

Comment: I have made an edit to my question and added snippet. It doesn't work can you check?